# has anyone implemented a show command in apache calcite adapter

Tags: mysql, postgresql, apache-calcite

I am looking to implement a `show foo` command relevant to the database engine we would like to hook up to Calcite via a Calcite adapter.  `foo`, of course, being something specific to that database engine.  I am trying to figure out what kind of relnode(s) to map it to (and other details).  So, if someone has implemented a "show" statement as a Calcite adapter and has some hints for me they would be appreciated.

My current thought is to make a new "foo" table type with the relevant columns for what the command should return and then map `show foo` to the equivalent of:

```sql
select * from foo;
```

Doing that with Calcite relnodes, of course.  At the backend, I know what I have to translate it to.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at [sqlline](https://github.com/julianhyde/sqlline) which implements `show`-like commands: `!dbinfo`, `!tables`, `!schemas`, etc. If you look at [Commands.java](https://github.com/julianhyde/sqlline/blob/main/src/main/java/sqlline/Commands.java), you will see they're implemented via JDBC.

From there, however, you can pickup the Calcite side of it in the various classes in the [org.apache.calcite.jdbc](https://github.com/apache/calcite/tree/master/core/src/main/java/org/apache/calcite/jdbc) namespace.